# C++ Move copy constructor and Move Assignment operator

Tags: c++, class, runtime-error, copy-constructor, move-semantics

I have made a simple application with move copy constructor and move copy assignment operator and on each of them I have made a cout statement just to tell me, which are being executed. But during execution, I did not see any statement from the move copy operators but only from default one which the compiler already provides. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Names{
private:
    string* name;
public:
    Names(string place_name){
        cout << "Overloaded constructor" << endl;
        name = new string;
        *name = place_name;
    }
    //copy constructor
    Names(Names& cpy){
        cout << "Copy constructor" << endl;
        name = new string;
        *name = *cpy.name;
    }
    //assignment 
    Names& operator =(const Names& cpy){
        cout << "Assignment operator" << endl;
        name = new string;
        *name = *cpy.name;
        return *this;
    }
    //move constructor
    Names(Names&& cpym){
        cout << "Copy move constructor" << endl;
        name = cpym.name;
        cpym.name = NULL;
    }
    //move assignment operator
    Names& operator=(Names&& cpym){
        cout << "Copy assignment operator" << endl;
        delete name;
        name = cpym.name;
        cpym.name = NULL;
        return *this;
    }
    //destructor
    ~Names(){
        cout << "Deallocating memory" << endl;
        delete [] name;
    }
};

int main(){
    Names nme("Bob");
    Names copin("something");
    copin = nme;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

and here is the output

[image: Output screen]

so the main question are

```
1) Why isn't the cout statement being show for the move constructor?
2) Is my declaration for move constructor correct
```

and Thanks you.

Comment: You should get in the habit of using a constructor initializer list and `nullptr`. Otherwise, I'm not sure why you're expecting the move constructor to be called at all, and the compiler can still generate move versions for you.

Comment: Like how exactly @chris because I am new to c++  and I would be even better if you can show me the coded version

Comment: I'd suggest a [book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) then. Plus there's tons of information about each thing I mentioned on the Internet.

Comment: @chris I got this information from 'Sams teaches yourself c++ in 21 days' and where can I find your tutorials?

Comment: I wasn't referring to any specific tutorial. They're all over the place and accessible through Google. The only specific thing I referred to was that list of books (and note that this particular book is not overly well-received).

Comment: @chris well anyway, what could be the solution to this. Is there anything I'd have to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use std::move for the move constructor and move assignment operator to work. See my main function below:

```
Names A(Names name) {
    return name;
}
int main(){
    Names nme("Bob");
    Names copin("something");
    cout << "before std::move(nme);" << endl;
    copin = std::move(nme);
    cout << "before std::move(GetName());" << endl;
    Names tom = std::move(nme);
    cout << "before A(Names(\"dick\");" << endl;
    // move constructor is also called when using temp rvalue
    Names dick = A(Names("dick"));
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Overloaded constructor
Overloaded constructor
before std::move(nme);
Copy assignment operator
before std::move(GetName());
Copy move constructor
before A(Names("dick");
Overloaded constructor
Copy move constructor
Copy constructor
Deallocating memory
Deallocating memory
Press any key to continue . . .
```

One more issue, your destructor should not delete [] name, just delete name;

Comment: This was a really nice one @uncletall but just one question I have got for you. Do I have to call move explicitly in order to invoke move constructor? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you need to call it explicitly. See here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor

Comment: Thanks @uncletall you've been a great help.